# Granite DS 2.2.0 exception-converters configuration issue

Tags: java, graniteds

Have problem with configuring exception-converters in Granite DS 2.2.0 on java side. I'm using Weblogic.
Steps done:
1. Implemented ExceptionConverter
2. Added next to granite-config.xml:

```
<exception-converters>
    <exception-converter type="<my converter full class name>"/>
</exception-converters>
```

3. Created empty WEB-INF/granite-config.properties

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**:
It should be used extended service exception handler in **services-
config.xml**, the default one does not handle exception converters.

```
<factory id="..." class="...">
    <properties>
        <service-exception-handler>org.granite.messaging.service.ExtendedServiceExceptionHandler</service-exception-handler>
    </properties>
</factory>
```

PS. Thanks to wdrai